# Button group overflowing on small viewport

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, buttongroup

I want to create a group button in a `<td>` element that'll behave the same on both small and large screens.

This is what I currently have.

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="edit btn btn-warning btn-sm">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Here's an screenshot to explain what I mean.

[image]

Comment: Can you create a demo of your issue? With your current code, issue is not reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apply minimum width to `btn-group` class on small screen media query

Answer (score 1):

You'll either need to apply a minimum width to `btn-group` or use one of Bootstrap's built-in classes such as `sm-col-1`.